# How to use 3 seperate filters on 1 page?

Tags: python, django

I have a page on which are 3 separate forms.
With form 1 I can filter on name (typed in by user) with form method Post
With form 2 I can filter on level (from list) with form method Get
With form 3 I want to filter on school (from list) also with form method Get

```
<!-- ### Filters ### -->

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'spells' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<h1>Filter Options</h1>
<div class="container ftable">
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="input-group ml-5 col-md-4">
    <label for="filter-search-name" class="form-labelz"><strong>Spell Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></label>
    <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="filter-search-name" id="filter-search-name" value autocomplete="off"
                placeholder="Give Spell Name or leave blank for all spells" spellcheck="false">
</div>


<div class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Filter</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<form method="GET" action="{% url 'spells' %}">
    
    <div class="container ftable">
<div class="input-group ml-5 mt-5 col-md-4">
    <label for="filter-search-level" class="form-label"><strong>Spell Level: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></label>
    <select id="filter-search-level" name="filter-search-level" class="form-select">
        <option selected value='Cantrip'>Cantrip</option>
        <option value='1st'>1st</option>
        <option value='2nd'>2nd</option>
        <option value='3rd'>3rd</option>
        <option value='4th'>4th</option>
        <option value='5th'>5th</option>
        <option value='6th'>6th</option>
        <option value='7th'>7th</option>
        <option value='8th'>8th</option>
        <option value='9th'>9th</option>
    </select>
    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Filter</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<form method="GET" action="{% url 'spells' %}">

    <div class="container ftable">
    <div class=" input-group ml-5 mt-5 col-md-4">
    <label for="filter-search-school" class="form-label"><strong>Spell School: &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></label>
    <select id="filter-search-school" name="filter-search-school" class="form-select">
        <option selected value='Abjuration'>Abjuration</option>
        <option value= 'Conjuration'>Conjuration</option>  
        <option value= 'Divination'>Divination</option>  
        <option value= 'Enchantment'>Enchantment</option>  
        <option value= 'Evocation'>Evocation</option>  
        <option value= 'Illusion'>Illusion</option>  
        <option value= 'Necromancy'>Necromancy</option>  
        <option value= 'Transmutation'>Transmutation</option>  
    </select>
    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Filter</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- ### END Filters ### -->
```

Currently form 1 and 2 work, giving a filtered list a little lower on the same page.
form 3 is working too (the right choice is visible behind the URL) but the filtered list stays empty.

part of views.py:

```
def spells(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        spellz = request.POST.get('filter-search-name')    
        spells = Underdark_Spells.objects.filter(Q(spell_name__icontains=spellz)).order_by('spell_name')
        return render(request, 'spells.html', {'spells': spells})
    elif request.method == "GET":
        level = request.GET.get('filter-search-level')    
        spells = Underdark_Spells.objects.filter(Q(spell_level=level)).order_by('spell_name')
        return render(request, 'spells.html', {'spells': spells})  
    elif request.method == "GET":
        school = request.GET.get('filter-search-school')    
        spells = Underdark_Spells.objects.filter(Q(spell_school=school)).order_by('spell_name')
        return render(request, 'spells.html', {'spells': spells})       
    else:
        spells = Underdark_Spells.objects.all().order_by('spell_name')
        return render(request, 'spells.html', {'spells': spells}) 

    

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I think the problem is with the way I set it up with if and elif
It looks like this way I can not use request method twice in the same if statement.
If I comment out form 2 code in views.py then form 3 works like a charm.

Is there a way to make it work like this or do i have to create a seperate def for each GET?

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Ok thanks i fixed it. First it would not let me include the code, something about ident. But it works now..

Comment: these two identical consecutive conditions dont make sense: `elif request.method == "GET":` If the request is `GET`, it will always match the first `elif` and never the second one .  Put the code from both of them together and use model `filter()` only if the variable in `request.GET` has a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have identical conditions in two different if/elif blocks.

Instead you can do this as below:

```py
...
elif request.method == "GET":
    if request.GET.get('filter-search-level'):
        level = request.GET.get('filter-search-level')  
        spells = Underdark_Spells.objects.filter(Q(spell_level=level)).order_by('spell_name')
    elif request.GET.get('filter-search-school'):
        school = request.GET.get('filter-search-school')    
        spells = Underdark_Spells.objects.filter(Q(spell_school=school)).order_by('spell_name')
    return render(request, 'spells.html', {'spells': spells})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a check to see if the item is in the querystring, so:

```
def spells(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'filter-search-name' in request.POST:
        spellz = request.POST.get('filter-search-name')    
        spells = Underdark_Spells.objects.filter(Q(spell_name__icontains=spellz))
    elif request.method == 'GET' and 'filter-search-level' in request.POST:
        level = request.GET.get('filter-search-level')    
        spells = Underdark_Spells.objects.filter(Q(spell_level=level))
    elif request.method == 'GET' and 'filter-search-school' in request.POST:
        school = request.GET.get('filter-search-school')    
        spells = Underdark_Spells.objects.filter(Q(spell_school=school))
    else:
        spells = Underdark_Spells.objects.all()
    spells = spells.order_by('spell_name')
    return render(request, 'spells.html', {'spells': spells})
```

That being said, the code looks quite "ugly" with a lot of duplicated code. It is also strange to make use of a GET or POST request to search for data. Typically a GET request is used to filter data, a POST request is used to update entities. By using three different forms, you also make it impossible to simply select a level *and* a school for example to apply two filters.

I would advise to make use of *one* form where you have multiple items, and make use of [**`django-filter`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/) or at least of [*Django forms* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/) to remove boilerplate code.